# Displaying XML information in HTML from a Public XML source

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm looking for a very basic way to display one piece of XML data from this public source in html: http://avwx.rest/api/metar.php?station=KTPF

Here is what I have so far, with no luck:

```
                <script type="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    url: "http://avwx.rest/api/metar.php?station=KTPF",
                    success: xmlParser
                });
            });

            function xmlParser(xml)
            {
                $(xml).find("Raw-Report")
                {
                    $("#metar-text").append('<marquee class="metar-marquee">' + $(this).find("Raw-Report").text() + '</marquee>');
                };
            };
            </script>
```

I have a div in the HTML with the id #metar-text that I would like scrolling (hence the conc. marquee tags)  I only need to display the Raw-Report text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code require some corrections to work.

```
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({//this part is OK
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: "http://avwx.rest/api/metar.php?station=KTPF",
        success: xmlParser //note that success receives 3 arguments
    });
});

function xmlParser(data, state, xhr)
{
    var xml = xhr.responseXML; //xml document is here
    if($(xml).find("Raw-Report").text()) //that is exists and not empty
    {
        $("#metar-text").append('<marquee class="metar-marquee">'
          + $(xml).find("Raw-Report").text()
          + '</marquee>'); //**this** is $.ajax in this context
    };
};
</script>
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much!!  Thanks for the comments as well..it cleared some things up for me.

Comment: How do you show the result from the query in the html part?

Comment: @Whir FYI `marquee` is an HTML tag.